# ValueError: Inconsistent shapes: saw (1152, 10, 1, 10, 16) but expected (1152, 10, 1, 16)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am learning capsnet now, and trying to transfer the code from local computer to colab. 
The code runs well on my local computer, but raise an error when I try it on colab.
ValueError: Inconsistent shapes: saw (1152, 10, 1, 10, 16) but expected (1152, 10, 1, 16).

When I try other matching like [3,1], I will get the following error. In this case, x's dimension backs to 4 and x[3] == y[2].
ValueError: Can not do batch_dot on inputs with shapes (1152, 10, 1, 8) and (1152, 10, 8, 16) with axes=[3, 1]. x.shape[3] != y.shape[1] (8 != 10).

I locate the reason of this error on the function tf.scan. And I installed tensorflow 1.13 on my computer. But I don't know how to fix it. Please help me.

Here is the code.

```
class CapsuleLayer(layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, num_capsule, dim_vector, num_routing=3,
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 **kwargs):
        super(CapsuleLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_capsule = num_capsule
        self.dim_vector = dim_vector
        self.num_routing = num_routing
        self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
        self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) >= 3, "The input Tensor should have shape=[None, input_num_capsule, input_dim_vector]"
        self.input_num_capsule = input_shape[1]
        self.input_dim_vector = input_shape[2]

        # Transform matrix
        self.W = self.add_weight(shape=[self.input_num_capsule, self.num_capsule, self.input_dim_vector, self.dim_vector],
                                 initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                 name='W')
        print("the weight size in capsule layer", self.W)

        # Coupling coefficient. The redundant dimensions are just to facilitate subsequent matrix calculation.
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=[1, self.input_num_capsule, self.num_capsule, 1, 1],
                                    initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                    name='bias',
                                    trainable=False)
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        inputs_expand = K.expand_dims(K.expand_dims(inputs, 2), 2)

        inputs_tiled = K.tile(inputs_expand, [1, 1, self.num_capsule, 1, 1])
        print("call size inputs_tiled", inputs_tiled)

        # Compute `inputs * W` by scanning inputs_tiled on dimension 0. This is faster but requires Tensorflow.
        # inputs_hat.shape = [None, input_num_capsule, num_capsule, 1, dim_vector] [3, 2] [4,3]
        inputs_hat = tf.scan(lambda ac, x: K.batch_dot(x, self.W, axes=[3,2]),
                             elems=inputs_tiled,
                             initializer=K.zeros([self.input_num_capsule, self.num_capsule, 1, self.dim_vector]))
        print("result of inputs_hat", inputs_hat)

        # Routing algorithm V2. Use iteration. V2 and V1 both work without much difference on performance
        assert self.num_routing > 0, 'The num_routing should be > 0.'
        for i in range(self.num_routing):
            c = tf.nn.softmax(self.bias, dim=2)  # dim=2 is the num_capsule dimension
            # outputs.shape=[None, 1, num_capsule, 1, dim_vector]
            outputs = squash(K.sum(c * inputs_hat, 1, keepdims=True))
            print("size after squash:", outputs)

            # last iteration needs not compute bias which will not be passed to the graph any more anyway.
            if i != self.num_routing - 1:
                # self.bias = K.update_add(self.bias, K.sum(inputs_hat * outputs, [0, -1], keepdims=True))
                self.bias = tf.assign_add(self.bias, K.sum(inputs_hat * outputs, -1, keepdims=True))
                # self.bias = self.bias + K.sum(inputs_hat * outputs, -1, keepdims=True)
            # tf.summary.histogram('BigBee', self.bias)  # for debugging
        return K.reshape(outputs, [-1, self.num_capsule, self.dim_vector])

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        print("the output shape of capslayer is:", tuple([None, self.num_capsule, self.dim_vector]))
        return tuple([None, self.num_capsule, self.dim_vector])
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally, I solved it. 
Function `tf.scan()` here does nothing wrong, but does not accord to my environment. The purpose of `tf.scan()` here is similar to the fully connected layer.

According to the definition of fully connected layer, we just need to alter the function, but don't use `tf.map_fn()`, since that we'll get the same error.

And try this one. This function helps a lot to solve this problem.

Hope that my solution works one your problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on one machine and not the other. After comparing environments I found 2 discrepencies, Tensorflow was at 2.1 and Keras was at 2.3 on the machine with the error and 1.15.0 and 2.2.4 respectively for the environment that works.

First I downgraded Tensorflow and it did not work.

Second I downgraded Keras and the problem was fixed. So my conclusion is Keras 2.3 broke that function.